# How can I reload UIAlertView message

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I took this project from [github](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets).

It is custom AlertView. I understood how it works. Modified it for my project, like this

[image]

Course1 - name of some product, and '1' - is its amount. When I'm typing on plus/minus amount increases/decreases. But it works only for my variable (which I load on this AlertView, when I show it, and it is 1). How can I reload message of this alert view with changing var (amount). I can't understand.
Here my code.

In my class I call alert view by this code

```
BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle: title message:ac.acCount];

[alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"-" block:nil];
[alert setDestructiveButtonWithTitle:@"+" block:^{
            int u = [ac.acCount intValue];
            u++;
            ac.acCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", u];
            NSLog(@"%d", u);
        }];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok" block:^{
            NSMutableArray *container = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [container addObject:title];
            [container addObject:price];
            [container addObject:bId];
            [container addObject:ac.acCount];
            [container addObject:depid];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:container];
        }];
        [alert show];
```

Show method just draws alert view with params which takes from alertWithTitle: title message:ac.acCount. Here is the code

```
+ (BlockAlertView *)alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
 {
    return [[[BlockAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message] autorelease];
 }
```

here is

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message 
{
NSLog(@"title - %@ message - %@", title, message);

if ((self = [super init]))
{
    UIWindow *parentView = [BlockBackground sharedInstance];
    CGRect frame = parentView.bounds;
    frame.origin.x = floorf((frame.size.width - background.size.width) * 0.5);
    frame.size.width = background.size.width;

    _view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _blocks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _height = kAlertViewBorder + 6;

    if (title)
    {
        CGSize size = [title sizeWithFont:titleFont
                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width-kAlertViewBorder*2, 1000)
                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kAlertViewBorder, _height, frame.size.width-kAlertViewBorder*2, size.height)];
        labelView.font = titleFont;
        labelView.numberOfLines = 0;
        labelView.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        labelView.textColor = kAlertViewTitleTextColor;
        labelView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        labelView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        labelView.shadowColor = kAlertViewTitleShadowColor;
        labelView.shadowOffset = kAlertViewTitleShadowOffset;
        labelView.text = title;
        [_view addSubview:labelView];
        [labelView release];

        _height += size.height + kAlertViewBorder;
    }

    if (message)
    {
        CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:messageFont
                          constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width-kAlertViewBorder*2, 1000)
                              lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        UILabel *labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kAlertViewBorder, _height, frame.size.width-kAlertViewBorder*2, size.height)];
        labelView.font = messageFont;
        labelView.numberOfLines = 0;
        labelView.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        labelView.textColor = kAlertViewMessageTextColor;
        labelView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        labelView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        labelView.shadowColor = kAlertViewMessageShadowColor;
        labelView.shadowOffset = kAlertViewMessageShadowOffset;
        labelView.text = message;
        [_view addSubview:labelView];
        [labelView release];

        _height += size.height + kAlertViewBorder;
    }

    _vignetteBackground = NO;
}

return self;
```

}

I tried to use something like this

```
-(void)reloadAlertView: (NSString *) title: (NSString *) message{
[self initWithTitle:title message:message];
}
```

and call this from my class, where i shows alert view.

```
[alert reloadAlertView: title: newMessage];
```

Comment: can you post some code of what u r trying here?? BTW your Question is not very clear, what u actually want. make it clear plz

Comment: Just show your code, it is definitely possible to customize it the way you want.

Comment: Note, you are not using `UIAlertView` but a replacement that works without subclassing `UIAlertView` -> hence your subject and question text are, at least, misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need to  ref a new label in your CustomAlertView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *mylab;
```

then you can get the properties of this label by the object of the CustomAlertView.h class

```
BlockAlertView *alert ...;
alert.mylab.text = @"hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. solution  (simple , not required to hack the `BlockAlertView.m`)
   whenever the `+` button is click, the alert will be disappeared, and reappeared again.

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController {


        BlockAlertView *alert ;
        NSInteger value;
    }

    -(void) viewDidLoad {
      value = 0;


        [self reloadAlert];


    }


    -(void) reloadAlert {
        value += 1;


        __block ViewController* _self = self;
        alert = [[BlockAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Course1" message:[[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:value ] stringValue]];


        [alert setDestructiveButtonWithTitle:@"PLUS" block:^{

            [_self reloadAlert];


        }];
        [alert show];

    }
   }
```

1. solution , if you want to keep the `AlertView` remained, without popping up.

a. Modify `BlockAlertView.h` to bring `messageLabelView`  outside to be accessed from `ViewController`, so we can redraw the message later.

**BlockAlertView.h**

```
@interface BlockAlertView  { 
...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *messageLabelView;
```

You can also bring the `UIView *_view`  out of `@protected` and into `@property` instead, if preferred. In that case, `messageLabelView` can be access via _view 's subviews

b. Modify `BlockAlertView.m`  `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` to disable `removeView` function from being called if `buttonIndex == PLUS` sign button  - `buttonIndex` to be hardcoded to `0`.

There may be a better option to stop the execution thread inside the block obj of PLUS button, but I dont know how to do :)

c. Modify `BlockAlert.m`  `initWithTitle:message:` to add reference of `messageLabelView` into `labelView` during the render of message Label.

**BlockAlertView.m**

```
@synthesize messageLabelView;



     - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message 
    {
     ...
    // code to initialize messageLabelView
     if (message)
            {

               .... 
                // code to render labelView for message. add reference to messageLabelView
                 messageLabelView = labelView;
                  // [labelView release];


            }
    }

    - (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated 
    {
        if (buttonIndex >= 0 && buttonIndex < [_blocks count])
        {
            id obj = [[_blocks objectAtIndex: buttonIndex] objectAtIndex:0];
            if (![obj isEqual:[NSNull null]])
            {
                ((void (^)())obj)();
            }
        }

    // there may be a better option to stop the execution thread inside the block obj above
        if(buttonIndex == 0) {// or whatever index of Plus Button, dont removeView
            return;
        }

    // code to removeView below, keep as usual
        if (animated)
        {
           ...
        }
        else
        {
        ....
        }
    }
}
```

d. Change reloadAlert in `ViewController.m`

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void) reloadAlert {

    value += 1;

    alert.messageLabelView.text = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:value ] stringValue];
    [alert.messageLabelView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```